# Breaking down an HTTP request to the same API into several HTTP requests

Tags: angularjs

I have an API `/api/organizations/` that takes `limit` and `offset` as query parameters and returns by default 100 items if no limit is specified.

For performance reasons, the API will return a maximum of 100 items at once. But let's say I want all the available data. How would I go about calling the same endpoint multiple times and building the data object to be assigned to the scope only when all the data has been retrieved?

The API returns by default the total count of the items, so from the first request I know how many items I have to retrieve, but I'm not sure how to go about processing the requests in a smart way.

I could make the first call, save the response in a variable, and then keep incrementing the `offset` and making new calls until I reach the end, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

I am using the angularjs $resource service.

Comment: Look into `$q.all` this can recieve an array of promises and will resolve with the results of that array once they have all resolved. You can then split your calls up into different calls and return the `.all` promise out of your service so calling code will wait until everything's done. [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `$q.all`. I posted the way I did it below. I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this in a fairly small number of lines of code, using the angular's $q service. I'll post this as the answer, but if there's an even better way to do this considering the use case, I'll happily update the correct answer.

First I define the array that will hold the promises:

Then I make the first call to the API, and I limit the response to one item, because all I need from this call is the `count` which is the total number of items I expect to have when I finish everything.

Inside this call I build the `promises` array based on my limit and the total number of available items returned by the first call and then run `$q.all`. When all promises have resolved, I put everything together.

```
var promises = [];
var limit = 100;

Organizations.get({ limit: 1 }, function(response) {

  // set the number of promises the array will need to contain
  var promisesCount = _.ceil(response.total / limit);

  // push x promises to the array, incrementing the offset each time
  _.times(promisesCount, function(n) {
    promises.push(Organizations.get({ limit: limit, offset:  limit * n }).$promise);
  });

  // run everything at the end and put the results together
  $q.all(promises)
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.organizations = _.flatten(_.pluck(data, 'rows'));
    });

});
```

Comment: Looks good, its how ive implemented something similar. Just be aware im pretty sure the actual call will be made when you call `.get()`. Even if it resolves in the microseconds it takes to get to the `$q.all` promises chained will instantly resolve if the first promise has already resolved if that makes sense. May be worth extracting this logic out into a service however if possible and just return the promise from `$q.all`

Comment: Doesn't `$q.all` resolve only when all of the input promises (passed in the array) are resolved? If I understand correctly, you're saying that the first call to `Organizations` can somehow influence the chain, because it's essentially the same resource?

Comment: Your are correct `$.all` will resolve when all the input promises have resolved. However the request to the server (im pretty certain) is actually made with the `.get()`. Which means, whilst very unlikely, the server could have responded in the microseconds between your `.get()` and the `$q.all` meaning the promises within the array could have already resolved. I was just being pedantic with regards to your comment 'run everything at the end and put the results together'. Technically the server requests are already running by that point.

Comment: Oh right, I get now what you mean. Every time I push to the array, I actually make the call to the server and save the raw promise. I interpreted it wrong in the comments. I'm still grasping the promise API, but I have a better understanding after this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. It got me for a while. I was just being pedantic really but worth knowing as it could cause strange behavior if you extended this concept to bigger promise chains.